# Rails "missing helper file" is an installed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've run `bundle install` and installed, among other gems, `rmagick`. I have a file `helpers/images_helper.rb` which calls `require 'rmagick'`. Everything works on my local computer; however when I attempt to run this on Ubuntu (Amazon EC2 instance), the main page loads up with an error:

```
LoadError in HomeController#hello

Missing helper file helpers/rmagick.rb

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   rmagick
```

I ran `gem env` and looked in the directory where it says the gems are installed and, indeed there is a file called `rmagick.rb`. So what's going on? Why is it looking in helper files anyway?

Comment: did you put rmagick into some special group in your gemfile? it looks like the rmagick gem was not loaded into your rails application.

Comment: It's a line in the gemfile like any other, `gem 'rmagick'`

Comment: are you running your app with `bundle exec ...` ?